# Scraping all books based on the topic (Books.toscrape.com)

Tags: python, web-scraping

Scraping from the website [Books.toscrape.com](http://books.toscrape.com/index.html). Prompt the user for what topic they would like to see the available books for e.g. Travel, Science Fiction, etc.  Verify the topic is one that is available on the website and display all the book titles and prices for the books in that topic.  Several topics have more than one page. Make sure you're returning all of the books associated with the topic.

This is my first time web scraping, and need help acquiring the topic pages url. For example if the topic is "travel" the link is http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books/travel_2/index.html but I don't know how to actually get to it.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

topic = input("What topic do you want to see the available books for? ")

url = "http://books.toscrape.com/index.html"
response = requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
links = soup.find_all('a', href=True)
for link in links:
    if topic.lower() in link:
        URL=link
```

Whenever I run it URL is not defined, I've been stumped for a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're checking for the topic in the link, you also have to check for the href attribute: `if topic.lower() in link['href']:`. Also the website has relative links that have to be combined with your base link. You can use `urljoin` like this to fix the issue: `full_url = urljoin(url, link['href'])`.

Updated Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin

topic = input("What topic do you want to see the available books for? ")

url = "http://books.toscrape.com/index.html"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
links = soup.find_all('a', href=True)

for link in links:
    if topic.lower() in link['href']:
        full_url = urljoin(url, link['href'])
        print(full_url)
```